# view based NSTableView - NSButton subview not firing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am using a view based `NSTableView`. I put a button in my view and hookup its action/target to call the following method in the App delegate:

```
-(IBAction)fire:(id)sender
```

The button in the `NSTableView` does not call my method in the application delegate. However, if I place a `NSButton` in a regular view and do the same (hookup its action/target to call `fire:`) then it works.

I've created a [sample code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31175721/tv.zip) to illustrate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make your AppDelegate implement `NSTableViewDelegate`:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate>
```

Then add this method to the implementation:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSView *customView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"customview"
                                                 owner:self];
    NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    return result;
}
```

Finally, in your MainMenu.xib, connect the *Table View* `Delegate` outlet to the *App Delegate* object

Comment: `customView` is unused, right? Code is nice, but explanation is much better.

Comment: @tenfour it's a long time since I wrote this, but it seems to be unused. Copy paste error, I guess...